# Analog of "pitch circle" for straight-pull hubs?

Tags: hub, spokes, wheel-building

If I want to build a wheel with my selected rim and hub, I can calculate the spoke length given the rim ERD and a few hub dimensions, most important of them being pitch circle diameter.

For a straight-pull hub, how would the corresponding metric be called?

Reason for asking: on a few straightpull hub vendor sites, I don't see any hub metric which would let me calculate spoke length for a given ERD. I want to know what to search (or to ask) for.

Comment: Many manufacturers don't supply this info, and when they do it's sometimes wrong! Experience has taught me to measure the hub that's in my hands before calculating and ordering spokes.

Comment: You measure from the point where the J-bend would be, if the hub was drilled that way. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: @Noise thank you, I know how to calculate the spoke length if I already have the hub. My question is whether there's an established term to search/ask for, and if yes, what does it measure.

Comment: flange pitch circle diameter.

Comment: The diameter of the circle made by the holes drilled in the hub flange ^

Answer (score 6):

It's still pitch circle or flange diameter. (Flange diameter is the term used in some places, even though it's confusing and basically wrong. It's wrong because it's also the same term used to describe the outer diameter of the flange so mass producers can know ahead of time which machines can run them. This is why sometimes you see both a flange diameter and a PCD listed as two different numbers, but other times just flange diameter).

This is how DT shows it on [their spoke calculator](https://spokes-calculator.dtswiss.com/en/calculator) (select Straight Pull for hub type, then click the information icon by "pitch circle right"):

[image]

To understand this topic it's helpful to think through what the spoke length calculation formula is asking for and how spokes are measured. The formula is the same for straight pull and j-bend, so you really just need to know where to measure. The formula only wants a measurement of the diameter of the circle that the spokes are coming out of.

[image]

Straight pull spokes are measured from the tip of the threads to the start of the transition point with the head (image from Wheelbuilder.com):

[image]

You want to know the diameter of the circle described by the spokes at the center of their thickness at that transition line between shaft and head. So most of the time, basically what you're doing is taking a vernier caliper and squinting at the hub as you align each jaw with the center of the hole where the the head will end and the "nominal thickness" section of the spoke will begin.

You could measure from other points, like for example where the heads terminate and not where they transition, but then you wouldn't be using the established standards for how straight pull spokes are measured, so you'd need to convert. In other words, if for some reason you had to measure using only the imaginary circle formed by the ends of the heads, and not the transition point, you could do that and it would work fine but you'd need to know that extra distance, and then subtract it from the result to know which spoke length to order.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me about DT Swiss - they have what I was looking for, calling it "offset spoke hole". Posted as self-answer. This naming doesn't please my ear, but I don't have a better one.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the pointer to DT Swiss given by Nathan Knutson, I found what I was looking for. Drawing in their spoke calculator, screenshotted below, shows the additional parameter which straightpull hubs must encounter for. It's the thickness of the "spoke pair holder".

[image: spoke hole offset, picture from DTSwiss]

Comment: It isn't really an "additional perameter" as the spoke heads on a standard hub have to be offset too! In theory a straight pull hub could have the heads aligned but I haven't seen it.

Comment: @Noise Agree. I have seen standard hubs with spoke holes spread non-uniformly over the circle, but in pairs, which creates need for the similar adjustment of the spoke length. Although with standard hubs one probably can assume that the holes are evenly spaced (it will be visible immediately if not), while on straightpull hub the configuration producing same spoke length as "evenly spaced" does not stand out.